# AWS EMR Cannot Find Mapper File From S3 Bucket - no such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I'm trying to run the following command

`hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -files s3://foobar/hadoop-samples/wordSplitter.py -input s3://foobar/hadoop-samples/input -output s3://foobar/wordcount/output/ -mapper wordSplitter.py -reducer aggregate -verbose`

But Hadoop cannot find the `wordSplitter.py` file. I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1116934618409_1114/container_1116934618409_1114_01_000018/./wordSplitter.py": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:208)
        ... 23 more
```

I tried modifying the activity command to add the full path to the `wordSplitter.py` file in S3 likes this

`hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -files s3://foobar/hadoop-samples/wordSplitter.py -input s3://foobar/hadoop-samples/input -output s3://foobar/wordcount/output/ -mapper s3://foobar/hadoop-samples/wordSplitter.py -reducer aggregate -verbose`

But I got the same error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "s3://foobar/hadoop-samples/wordSplitter.py": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:208)
        ... 23 more
```

This activity command worked when I used the AWS provided public location of `wordSplitter.py` as follows

`hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -files s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/wordSplitter.py -input s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/input -output s3://foobar/wordcount/output/ -mapper wordSplitter.py -reducer aggregate -verbose`

But I cannot continue to use the public AWS location `s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/wordSplitter.py` I need to get the file from my own personal bucket now and for some reason it cannot get the file from my personal bucket.

**UPDATE:**

I found [this AWS Developer Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=32192) and I did in fact save the python script on my windows machine before uploading it to S3 but I deleted the file and copied it from the source location to my S3 bucket directly to address the concern mentioned in the forum using the following command `aws s3 cp s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/wordSplitter.py s3://foobar/hadoop-samples/wordSplitter.py` but this did not fix the issue I'm seeing. I still get the exact same error. (Note, I ran the `aws s3 cp` command from within my EMR cluster (I ssh into the box and ran the command)).

**UPDATE 2:**

The EMR Cluster is able to find the `wordSplitter.py` file using the command 
`hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -files s3://foobar/hadoop-samples/wordSplitter.py -input s3://foobar/hadoop-samples/input -output s3://foobar/wordcount/output/ -mapper wordSplitter.py -reducer aggregate -verbose`
when I remove my [SecurityConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-create-security-configuration.html) settings from the EMR cluster. I need to keep my [SecurityConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-create-security-configuration.html) settings though so I'm not sure what I need to do to my S3 bucket to allow the EMR cluster to access the file to use as the mapper.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone still dealing with this issue this fixed it for me:

hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -files s3://foobar/hadoop-samples/wordSplitter.py#wordsplitter.py -input s3://foobar/hadoop-samples/input -output s3://foobar/wordcount/output/ -mapper wordSplitter.py -reducer aggregate -verbose

According to the Apache Hadoop documentation on streaming. "The -files option creates a symlink in the current working directory of the tasks that points to the local copy of the file.". Multiple files can be separated by commas.

I was running a streaming job on AWS EMR (v6.3.0) and using hadoop streaming with the following arguments

hadoop-streaming -files s3://archit47bucket/Step1RelativeFrequency/mapperwithlogs.py#mapper.py,s3://archit47bucket/Step1RelativeFrequency/reducerwithlogs.py#reducer.py -mapper mapper.py -reducer reducer.py -input s3://archit47bucket/Step1RelativeFrequency/Transaction.dat -output s3://archit47bucket/Step1RelativeFrequency/NOP1

For some reason specifying s3 location with -mapper didn't seem to work but the above -files argument fixed my issue.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UseCase_Streaming.html